# Apple script - set path to a custom path

Tags: applescript

I found this on this site

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p to path to desktop -- Or whatever path you want
    make new folder at p with properties {name:"New Folder"}
end tell
```

I want to use a different path for instance `/tmp/newbusiness/`

It says "Or whatever path you want" How can I make it what ever path I want?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't delete questions which have been put on hold. Adress the close reason instead with an edit.

Comment: Also, where on this site (link) did you find this?

Comment: PaulDaniels, Welcome to **Ask Different**. -- Had you actually included this _code_ in your other, now deleted, question it would have been so much easier! Please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and if you want help debugging _code_ when it errors, then also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and conform your queries to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
    set p to (POSIX file "/tmp/newbusiness" as alias) -- Or whatever path you want
    make new folder at p with properties {name:"New Folder"}
end tell
```

**Notes:**

As coded, the target *folder* must already exist, e.g., `"/tmp/newbusiness"` otherwise it will error.

`path to desktop` is a **Scripting Additions** *built-in* and returns the *path* to your **Desktop** as an *alias*. Have look at: [path to (folder)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19)

If you want to *hard code* a *POSIX path* and using it in a `tell application "Finder"` *block*, then you need to reference it as `POSIX file` and in my example I coerced it to an *alias* as that is what **Finder** works best with. Have a look at: [as (coercion)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH5g-SW5)

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @PaulDaniels If you are satisfied with the answer you can press the tick (✔️) below the voting arrows. It lets the community and outsiders know that’s the correct answer and serves as a guide for the future. It also increases your reputation in the community.